# Finish proof for injectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f: X \to Y$ . $f$ is injective if and only if for every $Z$ and $g_{1},g_{2} : Y\to Z$ such that $g_{1} \circ f = g_{2} \circ f$ $\Rightarrow$ $g_{1}= g_{2}$. 
I have completed the solution for the analogue which deals with surjectivity by finding $g_{1},g_{2}$ that even if  $f \circ g_{1}=f  \circ g_{2} $ but $g_{1}\neq\  g_{2}$ by choosing :

$g_{1}=id_Y$   and

$g_{2} = \begin{cases} y & \text{if } y \in \operatorname{im}(f), \\ y_{2} fixed & \text{if } y \notin \operatorname{im}(f). \end{cases}$

So by supposing the opposite I have proven by negation that there exist $g_{1},g_{2}$ such that  $g_{1} \circ f = g_{2} \circ f$ but $g_{1}\neq\  g_{2}$

can someone give me a hint in defining $g_{1}$, $g_{2}$.
I know it is a bit confusing and maybe there are similar questions to this one but I am trying to prove the $\Leftarrow$ by using the assumption from reverse

Comment: What do you mean by reflection?

Comment: functional reflection

Comment: What do you mean by functional reflection?

Comment: it is just a way of saying that f is a mapping

Comment: So, a function? I've never heard that phrase, but all right.

Comment: The phrase "map" works too

Comment: ok thank I am from Italy so I didn't know how to translate but thank i will use the word map

Comment: I don't know if I am being clear in my proof of the surjectivity case  
@Omnomnomnom

Comment: I think you have the statement backwards: it should be $f$ is *injective* iff
$$
f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2 \implies g_1 = g_2
$$
and $f$ is *surjective* if 
$$
g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f \implies g_1 = g_2
$$

Comment: most rightly so

Comment: yes f you look closely the statement is right  I just have mentioned the case of surjectivity that in my solution by applying the reverse assumption  so if f is not surjective there exist g1 and g1 such ... but g1 not equal to g2, I don't know if I am making myself clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define your map in the proof for injective functions: let $x_1\neq x_2$ be such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Then, define $g_1,g_2:\{0\} \to X$ by
$$
g_1(0) = x_1\\
g_2(0) = x_2
$$

---

For the case of surjective functions: suppose that $Y \setminus f(X)$ is non-empty. We can then define $g_1,g_2:Y \to \{0,1\}$ by
$$
g_1(y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & y \in f(X)\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
g_2(y) = 1
$$

Comment: thank you sir, can you see the point I am making for the surjective case, I am not quite sure for that

Comment: It doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: how so if you can help me ?

Comment: I understand now, you have been a huge help I have been dealing with this exercise almost all day and it kinda feels bad when you see that you were wrong but also I am glad you gave me a correct answer, thank you sir